# Decrease 5 days from a date

Tags: php, datetime, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subtracting a certain number of hours, days, months or years from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382458/subtracting-a-certain-number-of-hours-days-months-or-years-from-date)

Hello, how can I decrease 5 days from a date like:

date("d.m.y");

-Thanks

Comment: you really couldnt find that in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=subtract+days+date+php?

Answer (score 3):

`date('d.m.y', strtotime('-5 days'));`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. and If I have a table with some dates and I want to delete for exemple all dates < 25.03.2011 ?

Comment: Then you will have to do it with a database DELETE statement.

Comment: I'd recommend working with timestamps if you are trying to do date math/comparisons.

Comment: I'd absolutely recommend **not** working with timestamps.  They don't account for DST, they don't account for timezones, they don't account for leap-seconds and the like.  Use a proper DateTime format both in the database and in PHP.  This is a solved problem, don't go trying to change things because you think arithmetic is easier...

Answer (score 1):

```
date("d.m.y",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-5,date("Y")))
```

Comment: doesnt take DST into account, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid strtotime when possible, it is slow

```
date('d.m.y',time() - 432000); // 60 * 60 * 24 * 5
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that there won't be any unexpected results when DST changes?

Comment: Thanks a lot !!.. I got it.. and for " If I have a table with some dates and I want to delete for exemple all dates < 25.03.2011 ? –"

Comment: DELETE dates FROM s_stats WHERE ?

Comment: @Mihail: how are you storing the dates in your database?

Comment: I agree you should avoid `strtotime`, but absolutely not because it's "slow" (it's not).  You should avoid it, because you should be using the [DateTime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) API...  To say it shouldn't be used because it's slow is down right misleading and a micro-optimization at best...

Comment: If you're doing date-type comparisons in the database, then don't do the date math in PHP. Most databases are perfectly capable of doing that internally already