# Subtracting days, months or years from date using php

Tags: php, date

I have a db table with a date field `startBefore` in `('Y-m-d')` format. There are also 3 other int fields representing years, months and days. What I would like to do is to fill these three fields the new `startAfter` date in `'Y-m-d'` format.

For example I have the '2001-11-14' as `startBefore` date and I would like to subtract 3 yrs, 7 months, 1 day to get the `startAfter` date.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subtracting a certain number of hours, days, months or years from date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382458/subtracting-a-certain-number-of-hours-days-months-or-years-from-date)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use `strtotime('date  -years -months -days')`

```
  <?php
    $time = strtotime('2001-11-14 -3 years -7 months -5 days');
    echo $date = date("Y-m-d", $time);
```

Comment: It doesn't work as the result is 1999-06-19 which is wrong. The correct for your example should be 1998-04-13.

Comment: it works fine for me it returns 1995-11-14 i'm subtracting 3 years 7 months and 5 days from it. check again and tell me

Comment: Yes, works ok. The result is: 1998-04-09. Starrting to subtract 3 years, 7 months, 5 days from '2001-11-14'. However I don't know if it takes into account the leap years and Feb.

Comment: I think the best way to do this is firstly convert years to days, months to days and adding the remaining days use your code to take the result. Thanks!

Comment: tomexsans has a better solution IMO, it is more OO, easier to read, less code, and more extensible.

Comment: For weekdays just use `-weekdays` instead of `-days`

Answer (score 31):

Here comes the `DateTime`:

```
$start_date = '2013-03-06';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$start_date);

$date->modify('+1 month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');//2013-04-06

$date->modify('+4 year');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');//2017-04-06

$date->modify('+6 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');//2017-04-12

$date->modify('+24 hours');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');//2017-04-13

$date->modify('-7 years');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); //2010-04-13

$date->modify('-18 months');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); //2008-10-13
```

So on and so forth.

Comment: ok, it works if you calculate on the current date: `$start_date = date('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 2):

You Could try

[`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) function in php its quite simple

```
<?php 
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11.12.10")); 
// outputs 10th December, 2011 

echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11/12/10")); 
// outputs 12th November, 2010 

echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11-12-10")); 
// outputs 11th December, 2010  
?>
```

Comment: To make this a worth-while answer could you please add examples/code.

Comment: Perfect! Down-vote retracted.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make the startBefore date a timestamp, than working with numbers and re-obtain the startAfter date, another way is to try to subtract days, months and years directly from the date.

Comment: How is possible to subtract days, months, years directly from the date? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, i where searching, it seem the you after all need to use timestamp, the "format" and subtract need the timestamp.