# How to subtract months from a date stored in variable?

Tags: php

If I use this way I can get what I want :

```
echo Date("m/Y", strtotime("04/2014 -1 Month"));
// 03/2014
```

but I need to generalize this to subtract from unknown date like this :

```
$date1 = date("m/Y", strtotime("+1 month"));
$date = date("m/Y", strtotime("".$date1." -$f month"));
```

I get wrong answers for date it show `01/1970` I want to know is it possible to use the date variable inside strtotime ? and is my way to use it right or wrong?

Comment: You didn't see this post in the sidebar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382458/subtracting-a-certain-number-of-hours-days-months-or-years-from-date?rq=1

Comment: So you want `$f` months before next month?

Comment: First method you use doesnt work as expected like yours `echo Date("m/Y", strtotime("04/2014 -1 Month"));` output `01/1970`

Comment: yes I want `$f` to be the number of months but this is not my problem I think my problem is it possible to show a variable before the `$f` or not? because if it is a real date it works but a variable not work why?

Comment: The problem is not the `$f` variable. The problem is `strtotime` and the `m/Y` format: http://codepad.org/L9NmTvQ1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [modify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) function.

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-04-01');
$date->modify('-1 month');
echo $date->format('m-Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the sub function

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-04-01');
$date->sub(new DateInterval("P1M"));
echo $date->format('m-Y');
```